# remove xticks and reduce space between observations matplotlib errorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar

I have done 3 experiments, and in each, I have recorder the mean and standard deviation of my values and I want to plot the corresponding error bars.

[image]

What I want is basically something like this:

[image]

But only one of each of the subplots above. My question is as follows:

- How can I put a label for each observation
- How can I put a different color for each observation
- How to reduce the space between the observations like above
- How to remove the xticks entirely as the plot above

The following is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

parameters = [1, 2, 3]
means = [0.0 ,0.39108616, 0.77254249]
stds = [0.05, 0.06666667, 0.08333333]
plt.errorbar(parameters, means, yerr=stds, fmt='o')
plt.show()
```

Comment: These are multiple questions. What's the expected output for your three experiments, exactly? What do you mean by "But only one of each of the subplots above"?

Comment: @Roy2012 what I meant to say, is that I want a plot exactly like the second figure in my question, the one for housing for example, and i need to do the questions above to achieve it

Comment: Okay. So no xticks, and a different color for each experiment? You refer to 'observations' in the question, but your data doesn't contain them, it only contains statistics about them. Do you mean experiments rather than observations?